# When I use createPattern, why does the same code work in W3Schools editor but does not work in VS Code editor?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a game using a spritesheet. This code was pasted into the W3Schools editor here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_createpattern. But, when I used this code in VS Code, it merely showed a black image.

```
<img src="https://www.spriters-resource.com/resources/sheets/49/52570.png?updated=1635821170" id="lamp" width="0" height="0">

<canvas></canvas>

<script>
  const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  const c = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  const img = document.getElementById("lamp");
  const pat = c.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
  c.rect(0, 0, 150, 150);
  c.fillStyle = pat;
  c.fill();
</script>
```

Comment: the image hasn't loaded yet, you need to wait for it to load

Comment: Do you have access to image source? Try downloading  the image ang using locally.

Answer (score 1):

The image hasn't loaded before the code runs

Wait for the image to load

```html
<img src="https://www.spriters-resource.com/resources/sheets/49/52570.png?updated=1635821170" id="lamp" width=0 height=0>

<canvas></canvas>

<script>
  const img = document.getElementById("lamp");
  // wait for image to load
  img.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    const c = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
    canvas.width = innerWidth;

    const pat = c.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
    c.rect(0, 0, 150, 150);
    c.fillStyle = pat;
    c.fill();
  })
</script>
```